# FFMpeg No such file or directory

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, h.264

I'm trying to convert a MP4 file to H264 using FFMPEG. Unfortunately, it get a file/directory each time "No such file or directory". I've followed the steps within this link https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows/20496#20496 / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjtmgCb8NcE, but it didn't work.

[image: Error Message]

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Show your command.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, I used **snap** to install ffmpeg. It installed version 4.3.1 and the error "No such file or directory" occurred.

To solve, I uninstalled it with **snap remove ffmpeg** and installed with **apt-get install ffmpeg**. Apt-get installed version 3.4.8. Then, it worked.

Comment: This one worked in my case. Don't know what was happening though. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Check the full path of input file.

Adding paths to PATH env variable is preferred to set using cmd like this(for permanently)

```
setx path "%path%;Path"
```

Now restart cmd and retry again.

Comment: Changed the path to "%path%;Path" in the env variable but still received the error.